# Where can I buy packaging without buying bulk?

Tags: presentation

I am just an almost-professional photographer, just building my portfolio and doing some engagement and individual sessions here and there. 
Is there a place online (USA preferably) where I can purchase inexpensive photo packaging such as PORTRAIT CASES, without buying in bulk? 
I prefer plain and simple, with NO fancy ribbons or anything, because I will be doing my own special packaging. I just need the basic portrait cases or boxes.

The starter packs have too many, and are too expensive. I have tried Rice Studio, and HB or whatever it is, and DNL. I like DNLphoto.com and their portrait cases.

I am just looking at maybe UNDER 25 pieces, or just a couple of 5x7, couple of 8x10, few 4x6.

Answer (score 4):

If you only need a handful just make them yourself. You can buy all sorts of interesting paper/card stock at art supply stores. Once you've developed a pattern, it doesn't take long to trace it onto your final material and cut it out with an Xacto knife, rotary cutter, or just a good pair of scissors. Use a [bone folder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone_folder) to help you create straight, smooth folds.

Making your own means that you can play with form and features as much as you like. Add a little window to let your photo peek through. Use Vecro dots, natural raffia, or even bits of thin plastic magnet material for closures. Keep it neat, but don't be afraid to let the fact that it's handmade show.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ebay? That's where I tend to look for low quantity packaging items when I need them.

I've not specifically looked for portrait cases, but there are usually all kinds of packaging available from sellers, in quantities ranging from individual items to box quantities. It might not be the cheapest way to get things in terms of unit cost - but it's usually easy - and if you're concerned about unit cost, it makes more sense to buy in bulk anyway.